# How can I get the ID and the name of the discovered devices?

Tags: reactjs, bluetooth-lowenergy, native

I am working with React Native and I am very new to BLE. I am finding the devices, at least my log says that, but I can't get any info like name or ID of the device so that I can start with connection to the BLE device.

```
  const handleConnect = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          title: 'Location Permission',
          message:
            'This app needs access to your location for Bluetooth scanning',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        },
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log('You can use the location');
      } else {
        console.log('Location permission denied');
        return;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }

    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
        {
          title: 'Bluetooth scan',
          message: 'This app needs access to your bluetooth for scanning',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        },
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log('You can use bluetooth');
      } else {
        console.log('Bluetooth permission denied');
        return;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }

    BleManager.start({showAlert: false});

    BleManager.scan([], 5, true)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Scanning...');
        setTimeout(() => {
          BleManager.getDiscoveredPeripherals([]).then(peripheralsArray => {
            // Success code
            console.log('Amount of Discovered peripherals: ', peripheralsArray.length);
            console.log('Discovered peripherals: ', peripheralsArray);
            console.log('Discovered peripheral 0 id: ', peripheralsArray[0].id);
            console.log('Discovered peripherals 0 name: ', peripheralsArray[0].name);
          });
        }, 5000);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Scan error', error);
      });
  };
```

I dont understand the problem in my code. What am I doing wrong? Here is my log.
[image]

Comment: Have you logged the array to verify its structure? Maybe there are no properties with those names, or maybe they're deeper in the data.

Comment: Do you have [these permissions granted](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/blob/v.11.0.5/example/plugins/withBLE.ts#L31-L33) for your application?

Comment: Yes as you can see in the picture of the log I have the array and 5 devices.
Permissions is there and it works as you can see the picture of the log